# Quartz.NET skipping steps during execution

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need your valuable advice on QUARTZ.NET . I am using this scheduling to run my function after every 10 seconds. Actually my code is getting data from json files and compare it with database SQL server. If the id match the database then it will not do anything otherwise it will tweet the product. Some time code run successfully I got not duplicate entries. But sometime it insert the duplicate values in the database and it is only possible to skip the  exist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); Please tell me what should do. Because i cannot increase the time of schedular from more than 10seconds. And how to stop missing the single line in that. Below is my code. It will be great help to me .. Please help. Thanks

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.Start();
                // scheduler.ResumeAll();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>()
                               .WithIdentity("currencyJob", "group1")
                               .Build();

                //  IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>().Build();
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                         .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                         .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInSeconds(15).RepeatForever())
                         .Build();

                //ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                //              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
                //              .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

and Sample.cs is below

```
   public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {


            tweetmonitor();
        }

        public void tweetmonitor()
        {
            ////////////////////////////////URLS And Proxy tables data get//////////////////////////////////
            List<UrlKeyword> employee = new List<UrlKeyword>();
            List<Proxy> proxy = new List<Proxy>();
            List<ProductsJsonModel> json = new List<ProductsJsonModel>();
            ProductsJsonModel json2 = new ProductsJsonModel();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

            SqlCommand customer = new SqlCommand("select * from customer", conn);
            SqlCommand cmdproxy = new SqlCommand("select * FROM ProxyTable", conn);

            customer.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            try { 
            conn.Open();


            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlDataReader rdr = customer.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                UrlKeyword emp = new UrlKeyword();

                emp.url = rdr["ContactName"].ToString();
                emp.keywords = rdr["CompanyName"].ToString();

                employee.Add(emp);
            }
            rdr.Close();


            SqlDataReader rdrproxy = cmdproxy.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdrproxy.Read())
            {
                Proxy pr = new Proxy();

                pr.IP = rdrproxy["IP"].ToString();
                pr.Port = Convert.ToInt32(rdrproxy["Port"]);
                pr.UserName = rdrproxy["UserName"].ToString();
                pr.PassWord = rdrproxy["PassWord"].ToString();
                proxy.Add(pr);

            }
            rdrproxy.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///////////////////Checking from database/////////////////////////

            ///////////////////Checking from database/////////////////////////


            foreach (var x in employee)
            {

                foreach (var m in proxy)
                {


                    try
                    {
                        string url = x.url;
                        string keyword = x.keywords;
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(x.url);
                        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(m.IP, m.Port);
                        if (m.UserName != null && m.PassWord != null && m.UserName != "" && m.PassWord != "")

                        {
                            myproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(m.UserName, m.PassWord);
                        }
                        myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;

                        request.Proxy = myproxy;
                        request.Method = "GET";
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                        if (response != null)
                        {
                            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                            string mr = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                            /////////////////JSON Data///////////////////
                            if (x.url.Contains("json"))
                            {
                                //JSON files to twitter
                                try
                                {
                                    ProductsJsonModel Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsJsonModel>(mr);
                                    List<Product> ProductsFromUrl = Data.products;
                                    int countofloop;
                                    countofloop = ProductsFromUrl.Count;

                                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                                    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                                    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                                    {
                                        conn.Open();
                                    }

                                    cmd.CommandText = "select IdJson from  dbo.JsonDataPrimary";
                                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                                    da.Fill(ds, "JsonDataPrimary");

                                    for (int s = 0; s < countofloop; s++)
                                    {
                                        int exist = 0;
                                       // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                                        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.JsonDataPrimary WHERE IdJson= '" + ProductsFromUrl[s].id + "'";
                                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                                        exist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                                        //////////////////////////duplicate check////////////////////////////////////


                                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                                        //   if (exist > 0)
                                        if (checkDuplicateTitle(ds.Tables["JsonDataPrimary"].Rows, ProductsFromUrl[s].id.ToString()) && exist > 0)
                                        {
                                            ///exit from here
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {

                                            string logstweetout = published_at + Environment.NewLine + product_title + Environment.NewLine + newurlimage;

                                            string logsdata = published_at + Environment.NewLine + product_title + Environment.NewLine + newurlimage + Environment.NewLine + "Variants(According to size)" + Environment.NewLine + variantscheck + Environment.NewLine;
                                               cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.JsonDataPrimary VALUES('" + ProductsFromUrl[s].id + "','" + ProductsFromUrl[s].published_at + "','','' ,'" + test + "')";
                                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                                        {
                                            conn.Open();
                                        }
                                        cmd.Connection = conn;



                                        }

                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {

                                }
                                conn.Close();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your code it is possible that 2 jobs are executing in  the same time => and so produce dublications. You may add `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute to your job class to prevent that:

> An annotation that marks a Job class as one that must not have multiple instances executed concurrently

Comment: Thankyou very much Set.. You solved my problem... God bless you

Comment: @ArslanAhmad happy to help, you can accept the answer then)

Comment: Hi Set i want to ask one more question. Due to [DisallowConcurrentExecution] my application is doing all the work complete in 30 seconds but i set the timer after 5 seconds interval. Can it possible to run the threads parallel . Mean when trigger will start the Sample job class and after 5 seconds it will trigger again to Sample job both will do their work?

Comment: @ArslanAhmad maybe understood you in wrong way, but actually, this is the default behavior without using [DisallowConcurrentExecution], as quartz use separate thread for each job and that was your initial problem (2 parallel jobs). From the other hand, read also about Quartz scheduler misfire instructions. They specify, how trigger should behave, when new job cannot be started.

Comment: Hi set ! I my above system is now doing not any duplication and i set the timer to 10 seconds but my system is going to slow now. It is tweeting after one mint release of product but I set the timer to 10 seconds. Mean trigger should do work after every 10seconds. But I think it is due to [DisallowConcurrentExecution] that firstly it complete one job and then start to work after its completion. Right? Please help me in this matter I need help. Thanks

Comment: @ArslanAhmad again, you need to look for misfires setup. With DisallowConcurrentExecution policy new job cannot be started until previous is done and so it is delayed or skipped. This may help you http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html  Also in your case it is better to update your current SO question or create the new one, as you now have a different problem.

Comment: OK Set thanks for your valuable device I will read the given url and then i did not understand anything then will ask the new question