# Quartz.NET delaying my Processes to tweet out

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Second Question on Quartz.NET. [Quartz.NET skipping steps during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055006/quartz-net-skipping-steps-during-execution/42070042?noredirect=1#comment71430789_42070042) This was the previous answer and I got the answer. Actually, I am tweeting out the products from 60 URLs data when any product is released then it will be checked by database SQL server and then if not found then it will tweet out. But when I used the [DisallowConcurrentExecution] It stopped the execution at the same time. But I am getting a very slow response from URLs. Mean product released at 5:00 PM and my system is tweeting it at 5:05 PM. 5 minutes delay.... According to my understand it is only due to use [DisallowConcurrentExecution].

This is my trigger after every 10 seconds

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
                ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
                IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();

                properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "sf";
                properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "25";

                if (!sc.IsStarted)
                    sc.Start();

                 IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>()
                               .WithIdentity("currencyJob", "group1")
                               .Build();
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                         .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                         .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
                         .Build();

                sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

And below is some sample.cs class

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class SampleJob: IJob
{
    public static int count = 0;
    public static string strConnString = "Data Source = 7c5710a7-6f53-469f-83e9-a6fa0066f918.sqlserver.sequelizer.com; Database = db7ca6fa0066f918; User ID = ""; Password = "" ;";




    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {   
        tweetmonitor();
    }

    public void tweetmonitor()
    {
        ////////////////////////////////URLS And Proxy tables data get//////////////////////////////////
        List<UrlKeyword> employee = new List<UrlKeyword>();
        List<Proxy> proxy = new List<Proxy>();
        List<ProductsJsonModel> json = new List<ProductsJsonModel>();
        ProductsJsonModel json2 = new ProductsJsonModel();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        SqlCommand customer = new SqlCommand("select * from customer", conn);
        SqlCommand cmdproxy = new SqlCommand("select * FROM ProxyTable", conn);

        customer.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try { 
        conn.Open();


        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader rdr = customer.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            UrlKeyword emp = new UrlKeyword();

            emp.url = rdr["ContactName"].ToString();
            emp.keywords = rdr["CompanyName"].ToString();

            employee.Add(emp);
        }
        rdr.Close();


        SqlDataReader rdrproxy = cmdproxy.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdrproxy.Read())
        {
            Proxy pr = new Proxy();

            pr.IP = rdrproxy["IP"].ToString();
            pr.Port = Convert.ToInt32(rdrproxy["Port"]);
            pr.UserName = rdrproxy["UserName"].ToString();
            pr.PassWord = rdrproxy["PassWord"].ToString();
            proxy.Add(pr);

        }
        rdrproxy.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

Please help me how can speed up the processes.

Comment: Thanks Florian Schaal for improvement in grammatically. Can you have the answer of above question?

Comment: Why you didn't accepts the answer to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42070042/6666799)? As you stated self, it answers your question. I checked your other questions and none of them are marked as answered, even the ones that solves your problems. It seems that you are not thankful and i don't help people that are not thankful.

Comment: Dear Rabban ! I marked as solved because it solved my previous problem of duplication of entries in database and I got the answer to use the [DisallowConcurrentExecution] for concurrent executions. But due to disallow the concurrent executions it is slowing the application working. As I explained above. Please read the last comment that person told me to ask the new question. I hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: How long does the job take? If the problem is caused by DisallowConcurrentExecution, then that would suggest the job takes at least 5 minutes and there is no way you can run the job every 10 seconds if it takes 5 minutes to run every time.